# Can't acces user-db after page reload using Pouchdb-authentication with couch-peruser-approach

Tags: authentication, reload, phonegap, pouchdb

I write the user-access functions in a Phonegap-app that uses Pouchdb and a Couchdb2.1-Server. After all the googling, I still cannot figure out how it is possible to **keep a user logged in after a page reload** so that he still has access to his own database (couch-peruser enabled). I use pouchdb-authentication plugin to ensure secure logging and it works quite well except for throwing a 401 "Unauthorized" error when trying to sync after page reload.

What I do on page start:
Within the device-ready-fct, I require the existant local db:

```
db_loc = new PouchDB('db_loc');
```

Then with userdb being the userdb-hex database couch-peruser creates:

```
db_loc.get(existantDocID).then(function(){
    //I do some checks (username inside doc,...)
    return db_loc.get(docID);
}).then(function(){
    console.log("requiring remote db for existing user.");
    db = new PouchDB('https://'+server+userdb, {skip_setup: true}); 
});
```

When I now run the proposed sync-function:

```
db_loc.sync(db, {
      live: true,
      retry: true
    }).on('change', function (change) {
      console.log("sync: yo, something changed!");
    }).on('paused', function (info) {
      console.log("sync: replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection");
    }).on('active', function (info) {
      console.log("sync: replication was resumed");
    }).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log("sync: totally unhandled error (shouldn't happen)");
    });
```

I get the following 401:

```
GET https://myserver:6984/userdb-6d617267726574/_local/peewqgTrWXVcjYO4BE8fWA%3D%3D? 
401 (Unauthorized), sync: totally unhandled error (shouldn't happen)
```

So my workaround would be to log the user in again, each time the page restarts. The db.login() does require the users password though. That is bad because my app needs to work offline - so I would have to save the users password to localstorage (bad idea, or encrypt (but how, offline?)) or let the user log himself in at each page reload. This again would lead to errors when the password was misspelled as soon as connection is gained.

Shouldn't the pouchdb-authentication plugin deal with this via the session-cookie? I really don't know how to deal with this because everywhere I read that pouchdb just does exactly this stuff for you (somehow).

I appreciate every hint! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using phonegap but I think what you need to do is use "db.getSession()".

That will return the username for the user that's logged in with "db.logIn()".

response.userCtx.name is the current user

Then you can use that to set:

db = new PouchDB('https://'+server+response.userCtx.name, {skip_setup: true});

[pouchdb-authentication/docs](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/api.md#dbgetsessionopts--callback)

Comment: Thanks, but that's already tested a lot. It seems like the AuthSession CouchDB sets is not used for follow-up requests from Pouch to Couch. This is strange - so Cookie Auth does just not work at all... Is there a example config of Couch for pouch-authentication usage that anyone can share with me?

Comment: Are you using "Couch per User"?

Seems to me when I turned that on it broke pouchdb-authentication. I didn't look into it very far though. I stopped using it and created both the user and DB myself instead.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! Yes, I use Couch-Per-User, so that's sth I can check out. How did you implement the per-user feature on your own (are you willing to show some code? would be very helpful)
cheers!

Comment: It's pretty easy really. Create a _user database and create a user file for each user and a database for each user. In the database set the "permissions" to only allow that user access. 

From there, use pouchdb-authentication to handle the logins and manage sessions. There's example code for that in the docs linked above.

if you go to cheerypc.com/app and look at the "auth.js" file it probably has most of what you need.